# Can I use a static c# SoapClient in my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5, soap-client, webservice-client

I am invoking SOAP web services in my MVC app, using a SoapClient created by adding a service reference in Visual Studio.

The standard usage code looks like this and works fine:

```
public ActionResult myControllerAction() {
    ServiceSoapClient soapPort = new ServiceSoapClient();
    ServiceResponse response = soapPort.myService(new ServiceRequest());
    ...
```

In the interest of minimizing object creation, I'd like to use a static SoapClient in my controller and reuse it in all of my controller actions, but I don't have a good test that puts concurrent load on the system to find out if the generated SoapClient is reentrant.

```
private static ServiceSoapClient soapPort = new ServiceSoapClient();

public ActionResult myControllerAction() {
    ServiceResponse response = soapPort.myService(new ServiceRequest());
    ...
```

Anyone know if the generated SoapClient code is thread safe?

Comment: Do you have *any* indication that creating *one more object* per request will have any impact on the system? It's almost certainly completely irrelevant.

Comment: Agreed that it is certainly irrelevant in any real terms of memory or cpu impact, but avoiding unnecessary object creation is just a good habit.  The WCF framework supports reentrancy, so if the generated code allows it then I'll only create a single client.